# get 15 bits CRC from any size bit array

Tags: java, c, crc

I transfer data like this:   [DATA - any size bit array][CRC 15 bits].

How i can get 15 bits CRC from any size bit array to detect accidental changes to raw data?

Here start of code:

```
byte crc[15];
int data_length = *any size*;
byte data[data_length];    // for example data = {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1}
crc = get_crc(crc);

get_crc - ?
```

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter said, your code example has no bits but bytes. I assume you´ve really want the last 15 bit out of some byte array named data and that you checked that data has at least 2 bytes.
It´s as simple as

```
short crc = (data[data_length - 2] & 0x7f) | data[data_length - 1];
```

Side note: Maybe you are aware of it already, but 15bit CRCs are not exactly the most reliable thing (but fast). If you data not completely unimportant, some better algorithm could make sense (SHA´s, or depending on the use case something else like ReedSolomon-encoding etc.etc.)